# I keep getting initialization errors with functions. (Run-Time Check Failure #3)

Tags: c++

I can get the code to compile but in the process I then get a "Run-Time Check Failure."  I'm not getting any sort of error to work with so this has been tough for me to figure out.  I am a beginner so any pointers in how my code is formatted would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
void getJudgeData(string jname, double &score);
double calcScore(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5);
double findLowest(double high1, double high2, double high3, double high4, double high5);
double findHighest(double low1, double low2, double low3, double low4, double low5);

int main()
{
    double score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, avg_sc, lowest_sc, highest_sc;
    // Ask for the score of each judge
    getJudgeData("Judge 1", score1);
    getJudgeData("Judge 2", score2);
    getJudgeData("Judge 3", score3);
    getJudgeData("Judge 4", score4);
    getJudgeData("Judge 5", score5);

    //Outputs the average value
    avg_sc = calcScore(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
    lowest_sc = findLowest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
    highest_sc = findHighest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
    cout << avg_sc;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

/* getJudgeData asks the user for a score between 1 and 10
gets store in a reference value and validates the input. */
void getJudgeData(string jname, double &score)
{
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "\nEnter the score for " << jname << " Score must be in range 0 - 10: ";
    cin >> score;
    while (cin.fail() || score < 1 || score > 10)
    {
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cout << "Invalid. Please enter a valid score from 1-10: ";
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else
            cout << "Invalid. Please enter a valid score from 1-10: ";
            cin >> score;
        }
}

/* calcScore calculates and return the average of 4 scores that remain after
dropping the highest and lowest scores of the performer received. */
double calcScore(double _score1, double _score2, double _score3, double _score4, double _score5)
{
    double rtValue;
    double lowest_sc = findLowest(_score1, _score2, _score3, _score4, _score5);
    double highest_sc = findHighest(_score1, _score2, _score3, _score4, _score5);

    rtValue = ((_score1 + _score2 + _score3 + _score4 + _score5) - (lowest_sc + highest_sc)) / 3;

    return rtValue;
}

double findLowest(double low1, double low2, double low3, double low4, double low5)
{
    double lowest_sc;

    if ((low1 < low2) && (low1 < low3) && (low1 < low4) && (low1 < low5))
    {
        lowest_sc = low1;
    }
    else if ((low2 < low1) && (low2 < low3) && (low2 < low4) && (low2 < low5))
    {
        lowest_sc = low2;
    }
    else if ((low3 < low1) && (low3 < low2) && (low3 < low4) && (low3 < low5))
    {
        lowest_sc = low3;
    }
    else if ((low4 < low1) && (low4 < low2) && (low4 < low3) && (low4 < low5))
    {
        lowest_sc = low4;
    }
    else if ((low5 < low1) && (low5 < low2) && (low5 < low3) && (low5 < low4))
    {
        lowest_sc = low5;
    }
    return lowest_sc;
}

double findHighest(double high1, double high2, double high3, double high4, double high5)
{
    double highest_sc;

    if ((high1 > high2) && (high1 > high3) && (high1 > high4) && (high1 > high5))
    {
        highest_sc = high1;
    }
    else if ((high2 > high1) && (high2 > high3) && (high2 > high4) && (high2 > high5))
    {
        highest_sc = high2;
    }
    else if ((high3 > high1) && (high3 > high2) && (high3 < high4) && (high3 > high5))
    {
        highest_sc = high3;
    }
    else if ((high4 > high1) && (high4 > high2) && (high4 > high3) && (high4 > high5))
    {
        highest_sc = high4;
    }
    else if ((high5 > high1) && (high5 > high2) && (high5 > high3) && (high5 > high4))
    {
        highest_sc = high5;
    }
    return highest_sc;
}
```

Comment: You're a beginner, and you wrote *this* ? Interesting. So, were it me I'd start by ensuring both `highest_sc` and `lowest_sc` have *default* values before entering into the malaise of those if-else-if stacks. If none of the if-clauses match up, both of those will return uninitialized data. ex: two identical values being the smallest in the sequence (but being equal) will result in none of the clauses to find-smallest answering true (you're using strictly-less).

Comment: I wish I could have written this code instead of those hello world kind of programs when I was a beginner. :(

Comment: WhozCraig, I'm not *too* much of a beginner.  I've taken a Python course and this is my first C++ course.  This is my fifth project for the C++ course.  I still don't even have a year of programming experience under my belt so I still consider myself a noobie.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of Variable is not initialized.
But I think it should be run well, too. And I ran it well in MacOX.
Here are the tips:
**every variable should be initliazed.**
Change 

`double score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, avg_sc, lowest_sc, highest_sc;` to 

`double score1 = 0, score2 = 0, ...`

use `array` instead of so many similar variables

use `sort` to sort out the lowest and highest score instead of some many `if-else if - else`

Comment: We're not using arrays yet.